# Why am I getting "Unable to execute dex" in my worklight app

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I am new to worklight and am trying to understand the baic workflow. so i googled a little bit and found a link to start with a simple HelloWorklight project. But i am getting the following errror.

```
[2014-08-13 10:12:59 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat;
[2014-08-13 10:12:59 - IBMScanScannerAndroid] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat;
```

Also my eclipse says `No ipv4 address found`. my ip addresss is correct. Am i missing something?  Please suggest me any configuration settings to be changed or something. I would be happy to see a basic app running on my phone.

I follow by https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/WASFAQs/entry/using_a_barcode_scanner_with_worklight?

Html: i tried both the code given above and also just text "hello Worklight". 
Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would rather appreciate if you let my fault be clearly known rather than giving negative or something. Not everyone know eveything.

Comment: Your question is lacking; you do not provide any steps you've done in order to reproduce this error; start with a blank app.

Comment: Additionally, the link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see a basic app running on your phone, you **should not** start with a *not-basic app* (like an app that utilizes a Cordova plug-in).

Instead, you should read the [IBM Worklight Getting Started training modules](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/library/), where you will understand how to run a Worklight app at first, and then how to run a Worklight-based Android app on your device.

Please start from there.

Additionally, the IP-related log line is simply for your information; read it thoroughly. You can ignore it if you intend to work locally at this time.

If you want to see a basic "Helo World" app running on your device, read and then use the supplied sample project [in the section "Hello Worklight"](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_hello).